# Iquidus Explorer -[Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1338]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bitcoind

i hope you can answer my question. I just follow the Iquidus Tutorial for dummies. I installed the Iquidus explorer for my altcoin, but it keeps me giving an Econ error like described in the title. Maybe you have an answer to this.

Thanks in advance!

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1338] code: 'ECONNREFUSED',errno:'ECONNREFUSED',syscall: 'connect',address: '127.0.0.1',port: 1338 }
```

This is my Coin.conf

```
rpcport=1338 rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different port in explorer `settings.json` file other than you used in rpcport. Because `npm` and `rpc` both cannot connect to same port.
Simply change explorer port to 3001 , and if port 3001 is blocked on your system then do this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ufw

$ ufw allow 3001/tcp

$ npm start
```